# d3 - draw smooth line if two circles or points are close to each other

Tags: d3.js, svg

I want smooth lines. Currently drawing a independent circles but I want to do if two circles or points are close to each other then draw a line. Please someone help to write this in code in d3.js. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Or if there is any other way to get smoothing lines between points or circles.

```
const svg = d3.select('#svg');
let drawing = false;

function draw_point() {
    if (!drawing)
        return;

    const coords = d3.mouse(this);

    const c = svg.append('circle')
      .attr('cx', coords[0])
      .attr('cy', coords[1])
      .attr('r', 5)
      .style('fill','black');
}

svg.on('mousedown', () => {
    drawing = true;
});

svg.on('mouseup', () => {
    drawing = false;
});
svg.on('mousemove', draw_point);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only described effect you can use these svg filter:

```
  <filter id="smin">

    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic"  
                    result="blur"
                    stdDeviation="3" 
                    color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"></feGaussianBlur>

    <feColorMatrix in="blur" 
                   mode="matrix" 
                   values="
                      1 0 0  0  0  
                      0 1 0  0  0 
                      0 0 1  0  0  
                      0 0 0 19 -9
                   "></feColorMatrix>
  </filter>
```

It produces following image:

[image: example image]

Code example (you can drag circles):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="600" height="175">
  <filter id="smin">
  
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic"  
                    result="blur"
                    stdDeviation="3" 
                    color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"></feGaussianBlur>
                    
    <feColorMatrix in="blur" 
                   mode="matrix" 
                   values="
                      1 0 0  0  0  
                      0 1 0  0  0 
                      0 0 1  0  0  
                      0 0 0 19 -9
                   "></feColorMatrix>
  </filter>
</svg>

<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = 20;

var circles = d3.range(20).map(function() {
  return {
    x: Math.round(Math.random() * (width - radius * 2) + radius),
    y: Math.round(Math.random() * (height - radius * 2) + radius)
  };
});

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(d3.schemeCategory10);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('filter', 'url(#smin)')
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(circles)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y)
    .attr("cursor", "pointer")
    .attr("r", radius)
    .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
    .call(d3.drag() .on("drag", dragged));

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}


</script>
```